# bash script to extract values from zone files BIND and update as execute command

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, bind

I am trying to write a script that will extract the records (A,MX,TXT and skip the NS), from BIND zone files. (I've more that 700 zone file)
in order to execute with command. in new server as this utility (dns) will accept to add records only through this way

```
 /usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -a mail -ip 192.168.5.193
```

lets assume that the zone file like that

```
$TTL    900

@       IN      SOA     ns1.nameserver.tld. cp.domain.com. (
                        2016120503      ; Serial
                        10800   ; Refresh
                        3600    ; Retry
                        604800  ; Expire
                        10800 ) ; Minimum

domain.com.             IN NS   ns1.nameserver.tld.
domain.com.             IN NS   ns2.nameserver.tld.
mail.domain.com.        IN A    192.168.5.193
domain.com.             IN A    192.168.1.33
ftp.domain.com.         IN CNAME        domain.com.
domain.com.             IN MX  10 mail.domain.com.
```

and I need to extract the values (A,MX,CNAME ) with IP and add it on other server with below way ..like that

```
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -a mail -ip 192.168.5.193
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -cname ftp -canonical domain.com
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -mx -mail mail.domain.com -priority 10
```

Seeing as that is a bit convoluted, especially as the zone files contain different values, some are contain A record only and some contain MX and MX2 and some CNMAE and some not and so on. I'm not sure how to wring the bash I have written more than once but in wrong ways.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really go learn regular expressions and it'll be easy -- this isn't really a code-writing service. Here's a quick demo for what you could do if you knew just a little bit about regular expressions, and not in sed/awk etc. but in perl. The thing is that some of your zone files will probably contain something that doesn't work properly with these regular expressions, and you'll be on your own. So even if this place were a free code-writing service, it would be tedious to assist with the inevitable bumps along the way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

if (/^([a-zA-Z\.]*?)\.?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)\.?\s+IN\s+MX(\d?)\s+(\d+\s+)?([^\s]*?)\.?$/) {
    print "/usr/bin/dns -a $2 -mx$3 -mail $5 -priority $4\n"
} elsif (/^([a-zA-Z\.]*?)\.?([a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)\.?\s+IN\s+([A-Z]+)\s+([^\s]*?)\.?$/) {
    $subdomain = $1 || $2;
    $domain = $2;
    $type = lc $3;
    $address = $4;
    next if $type eq 'ns';
    if ($address =~ /\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.d+/) {
        $option = '-ip';
    } else {
        $option = '-canonical'
    }
    print "/usr/bin/dns -a $domain -$type $subdomain $option $address\n"
}
```

Output for your example:

```
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -a mail -canonical 192.168.5.193
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -a domain.com -canonical 192.168.1.33
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -cname ftp -canonical domain.com
/usr/bin/dns -a domain.com -mx -mail mail.domain.com -priority 10
```

Specifically, this code makes use of the following concepts:

`[a-z]` (character classes)

`\.` (escape '.' to get an actual '.' character)

`\s` (space character)

`...+` (one or more of the preceding character/character class/group)

`...*` (zero or more of the preceding character/character class/group)

`...+?`, `...*?` (same as above, but "non-greedy")

`(...)` (capturing groups)

`^` (beginning of line)

`$` (end of line)

`?` (preceding character/character class/group is optional)

As you can see you only need to know a little regex to make your productivity go through the roof.

Comment: yes that's what I was looking for .. only few thing about tge domains which we have it it's something like domain.com.uk  .. and ur script need to update it due they printed as com.uk